# Best Ruby library to validate request parameters

Tags: ruby, validation

I am designing a REST API and want to validate presence, length, etc. of request parameters.

For instance, I would like to validate things like:

- is 'name' provided in request
- is 'name' < 200 chars
- does 'age' has a numeric value
- is any unknown parameters provided
- 'customer_id' must be provided if 'name' is not present

And then check parameters like this:

```
request.valid?
```

I'm thinking about using DataMapper (or Virtus+Aequitas) or something similar. But DataMapper or another ORM just comes with so much functionality that I don't need.

How would you handle this and if using an ORM which can you recommend (based on number of dependencies and required "validation code")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ActiveModel::Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html).

It allows a lot of validations, like acceptance, associations, confirmations, exclusion, format, etc. For example:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :name, :surname, presence: true
  validates :city, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 18 }
end

# Example: 
p = Person.new
p.valid? # => false
```

I suggest you to take a look at the [ActiveRecord Validations & Callbacks Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Generally, these validations are used with the `ActiveRecord` ORM, but you could use it without ActiveRecord, as you can see [in this ActiveModel RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model).
You consequently just have to include the `ActiveModel::Validations` .

Comment: Is there a 'ActiveModel::Validations' gem or something that is not depending on ActiveRecord?

Comment: totally, just require `active_model`. Then you can follow most of the Yehuda Katz post http://goo.gl/Umjtn "ActiveModel: Make Any Ruby Object Feel Like ActiveRecord"

Comment: Well, I guess `active_model` is an acceptable solution. I have hoped for a solution more like DataMapper (Virtus+Aequitas) as the code looks way more cleaner. But unfortunately these libraries are not mature yet, at least not Aequitas.

Comment: normally you totally could use one of them with ActiveModel, as you don't need to use the ActiveRecord ORM, but just the validations in ActiveModel::Validations. But I don't know how stable are they.

Answer (score 1):

use already provides by rails validation for `name`, `age`. ref [`this`](http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/)

```
  validates :name, presence: true, :length => { :maximum => 200 }
  validates :age,  allow_blank: true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 18, :less_than => 100}
```

For custom validation use following

```
validate :some_validation_method

def some_validation_method


end
```

Comment: you're talking about ActiveModel, not directly Rails, even if its in its core now